# cassandra cql query substitution

Tags: cassandra, cql, pycassa

Explanation with an example:

```
import cql
cql connect to CF/Keyspace
last_key = XYZ (say it's getting fetched from else where)
cursor.execute(select * from domain_dimension where key=:key", key="last_key")
```

The CQL documentation says it can be done, but on console it says execute() got unexpected keyword argument.

Does Cassandra CQL really support query substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to pass the substitutions in a dict as a single arg, not as keyword args.

```
cursor.execute("select * from domain_dimension where key=:key", {'key': last_key})
```

That is how it specified in the example on the project homepage: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/

Comment: As in the python syntax is invalid or you get a cql exception that says it is invalid cql syntax?

Comment: the python syntax is invalid and error points at that line. Could you please try? thanks in advance

Comment: ah yeah, that isn't valid python. homepage there should be updated. I will edit my response.

Comment: Cassandra CQL Query Substitution really isn't working. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the new code in my response? What is the error now? It worked for me.